# Input to proprietary command prompt in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, user-input, command-prompt

I want to know how we can provide inputs to command prompts which change. I want to use shell scripting

Example where '#' is usual prompt and '>' is a prompt specific to my program:

```
mypc:/home/usr1#
mypc:/home/usr1# myprogram
myprompt> command1
response1
myprompt> command2
response2
myprompt> exit
mypc:/home/usr1#
mypc:/home/usr1#
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the way your question is asked I can't fully understand it. Do you want to pass `command1` and `command2` to `myprogram` automatically ? Could you post your expected input/output ?

Comment: Yes, `myprogram` is a 'C' executable which results in a new prompt, `myprompt>`  . I must send some commands in this new prompt, say write xxx. I get a response 'xxx written' and the myprompt returns until I type exit. After this , I am out of myprogram and back to my usual '#' prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to send specific commands to your program `myprogram` sequentially.

To achieve that, you could use a simple `expect` script. I will assume the prompt for `myprogram` is noted with `myprompt>`, and that the `myprompt>` symbol does not appear in `response1` :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#this is the process we monitor
spawn ./myprogram

#we wait until 'myprompt>' is displayed on screen
expect "myprompt>" {
    #when this appears, we send the following input (\r is the ENTER key press)
    send "command1\r"
}

#we wait until the 1st command is executed and 'myprompt>' is displayed again
expect "myprompt>" {
    #same steps as before
    send "command2\r"
}

#if we want to manually interract with our program, uncomment the following line.
#otherwise, the program will terminate once 'command2' is executed
#interact
```

To launch, simply invoke `myscript.expect` if the script is in the same folder as `myprogram`.

Comment: Thanks ! My linux flavour does not have `expect`. looks like I must build the package myself...

Answer (score 0):

Given that `myprogram` is a script, it must be prompting for input with something like `while read IT; do ...something with $IT ...;done` . Hard to say exactly how to change that script without seeing it. `echo -n 'myprompt>` would be the simplest addition.

Comment: myprogram is a 'C' executable

Answer (score 0):

can be done with `PS3` and `select` construct

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='myprompt> '

select cmd in command1 command2
do
    case $REPLY in
        command1)
            echo response1
            ;;
        command2)
            echo response2
            ;;
        exit)
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Or with `echo` and `read` builtins

```
prompt='myprompt> '
while [[ $cmd != exit ]]; do
    echo -n "$prompt"
    read cmd
    echo ${cmd/#command/response}
done
```

Comment: I want to execute `myprogram` also through shell script